# How to write rows to merged excel template by using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to save my dataframe data to a excel template, but the template's cell are merged. Please refer to the picture [image: pic]. May I know how can I input my data rows from dataframe to the template? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb= openpyxl.load_workbook(template)
ws = wb.active
rows = dataframe_to_rows(t, index=False)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):  #starts at 2 as you want to skip the first 2 rows
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Result: AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the top left cell of a merged cell, but not the others. In your case, you write to B5, C5... but NOT B6, C6,... or B7, C7,.... In the loop, you will need to skip rows 6-9, 11-14 and so on. As the whole template is not seen in your pic, I am assuming you want to write to rows 5, 10, 15. So, update this code (I have made minimal changes) in place of your for loops.

```
update_rows = [5,10,15] ## All rows you want to update (first r_idx only)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    if r_idx in update_rows:  ## Skip unless it is the first merged row
        for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
            ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx).value = 'New Value' #Replace with df values

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And yes, your assumption is correct. I have tried your code, and it runs without error but the template is still blank. I had tried with value = df.values and value = str('hello'). May I have your advice? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @ginnytsang - If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to ask how to add you dataframe values into the excel, right? In the ws.cell(..).value = "New value", the column will be updated with the text - "New value". So, if you need to update it with dataframe values, you should use df.iloc[1,1] in place of "New value", as an example, this will write data in df in second row and second column into the excel file.